# Insert muti values as separated by comma from one field to another field on JavaScript button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build a live search from and a onclick JavaScript button which copy the value from live search from to another filed. But replace the value.

Example, I search ICICI click copy ICICI coppied on 2nd field. Again I search HDFC click copy HDFC coppied on 2nd filed by replacing ICICI from 2nd filed.

But I want this, I search ICICI click copy, ICICI, (notice here is a comma after ICICI) needs to be inserted into 2nd field. Again I search HDFC click copy HDFC, needs to inserted into 2nd filed without replacing ICICI so final value of 2nd field will be ICICI,HDFC, and continue like this.

Please give me fresh JavaScript code for this copy feature, I will replace the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox1">
<button onclick="btnClick()">Searc</button>
<input type="text" id="txtbox2">
```

**JS**

```
var txtbox1 = document.getElementById("txtbox1");
var txtbox2 = document.getElementById("txtbox2");
txtbox2.value = '';
function btnClick(){
if(txtbox1.value){
    if(!txtbox2.value){
  txtbox2.value = txtbox1.value;
  }else{
  txtbox2.value = txtbox2.value+', '+txtbox1.value;
  }

}


}
```

[Working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knw8gbqc/7/)

Comment: Ooo hooo! It's was too easy. I done this in php hundreds times. But looks when I require in JavaScript I never think this logic will work. Sorry to disturb you. Thanks a lot